# C pointer to multiple functions

Tags: c, function-pointers

I want to pass to a function a pointer that can point to one of several functions.

What is the syntax for this?

```
void func_a(char c){
    //
}
void func_b(char c){
    //
}

void receiver(void (*function_pointer)()
{
    // do stuff with the pointer to the function, e.g. call it:
    function_pointer('a');
    function_pointer('b');
    function_pointer('c');
}

void main(){
    receiver(&func_a); // calls func_a with 'a', then 'b', then 'c'
    receiver(&func_b); // calls func_b with 'a', then 'b', then 'c'
}
```

Will the above work as expected? I assume a function pointer can only be used for functions with the same signature?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you get an error or are you just curious if this is correct?

Comment: I once had a similar problem with (optional addable) preprocessors on text files. you could solve it by having a struct with a functor, and a pointer to the next "step" in your function chain. you can then walk through the whole process by using something like `while( processor) { processor.exec(); processor = processor.next );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that looks like it should work.

And yes, you can only use the single pointer for functions sharing a signature.

Minor notes:

- You don't need to use `&` to take the address of a function, the function's name evaluates to its address in suitable contexts.
- Functions that are local and only intended to be used as callbacks (`func_a()` and `func_b()`) should be declared as `static`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do to make this cleaner is use a `typedef`. Define your function pointer in a `typedef` and you can use it in the arguments. Also you don't need the `&`. Example with your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void func_a(char c)
{
        printf("a:%c\n", c);
}

static void func_b(char c)
{
        printf("b:%c\n", c);
}

typedef void (*function)(char c);

void receiver( function func )
{
        func('a');
        func('b');
        func('c');
}

void main()
{
        receiver(func_a);
        receiver(func_b);
}
```

I learned this from 'learn C the hard way' link: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex18.html

Answer (score 1):

Function pointer to select one function among multiple functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
int plus(int a,int b){return a+b;}
int minus(int a,int b){return a-b;}
int multiply(int a,int b){return a*b;}
int divide(int a,int b){return a/b;}
int percentage(int a,int b){return a%b;}
void gec(int(**p)(int ,int),int c)
{
c=c%5;
if(c==0)
*p=plus;
else if(c==1)
*p=minus;
else if(c==2)
*p=multiply;
else if(c==3)
*p=divide;
else
*p=percentage;
}
int main(void) {
int a=100,b=20,c=12,r;
int(*fptr)(int,int)=NULL;
gec(&fptr,c);
r=(*fptr)(a,b);
printf("%d",r);
return 0;
}
```